# How can we assure that a Bitonic sequence will be formed from one longest increasing subsequence and one longest decreasing subsequence?

Tags: arrays, dynamic-programming

For example we have an `array[]={1,3,2,7,4,6,8,9}`.

longest increasing subsequence of this `array[]={1,3,4,6,8,9}` and its length=6.

longest decreasing subsequence of this `array[]={3,2}` and its length=2.

Then is Bitonic subsequence of this `array[]={1,3,4,6,8,9}`? if Yes then its length=6.But length of Bitonic subsequence =length of lis + length of lds -1,
here they are not equal.

if no how can you prove that length of bitonic subsequence=length of lis+length of lds-1

Correct me if I am wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: I think you are missing that the length of the bitonic subsequence should be "length of lis" + "length of lds" - "number of items that appear in both lis and lds". Also, shouldn't your bitonic subsequence include the "2" from the  lds?

Comment: @twalberg Given an array A[0 … n-1] containing n positive integers, a subarray A[i … j] is bitonic if there is a k with i <= k <= j such that A[i] <= A[i + 1] ... <= A[k] >= A[k + 1] >= .. A[j – 1] > = A[j]. .I found this from geeksforgeeks so how can 2 be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is correct and gives out 6 only... Consider the LIS[](as the LIS array) and LDS[] (as LDS array).. Now when  you iterate from left to right you reach the position where LIS[index]=6 i.e. LIS till array[7] is 6.. Now LDS[index=7] is 1 (Trivially one element is the maximum length of series)... NOW LIS[7]+LDS[7]-1=(6+1-1)

Now the Proof you wanted for Bitonic sequence... 
LIS[i],LDS[i] represents the Longest Increasing / Decreasing sequence till i!
Now, eventually you want to maximise it that's why you search over the sample space! So the answer will be maximum of (LIS[i]+LDS[i]-1) 0<=i<=n-1 ...
**That -1 is due to repeated inclusion of the element at i th position!**